# deploy exploded war on jboss 7 from intellij and maven

Tags: java, jboss, intellij-idea, java-ee-6, war

I have maven based Java EE 6 web application. 
I know it is possible to deploy it to Jboss 7 directly from Intellij Idea 11 as a war file.
But I'd like to be able to deploy it as "exploded" so that I can edit my jsp files and see result in browser imemdiately. Is it possible?

**EDIT**

Attaching exploded screenshot.
Now if I have configuration as shown on screenshot my JSP files are loaded from project.war directory not from src/main/webapp directory (even if this webapp dir is included). It prevents them from being reloaded.
I've already set "development" config param in Jboss 7.1.0.

[image]

Comment: You can configure and deploy exploded war artifact in IntelliJ IDEA: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html.

Comment: I am using it with a tomcat7 and it works.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my post with screenshot to picture where my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible from Intellij, but I think it would work if you added a [deployment scanner](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Deployment+Scanner+configuration) to your JBoss AS7 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **auto-deploy-exploded to true** in deployment-scanner tag in stanalone.xml in jboss 7 config

Ref: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-FileSystemDeployments

Answer (score -1):

In the Run/Debug Configurations dialog, select "Update resources" in the "On frame deactivation" drop-down. This way, when you switch to the browser, IDEA will copy resource files from their source location (src/main/webapp) to the directory where it build the exploded WAR to deploy.

Next, try running in debug mode and use hotswap to hot-deploy minor code changes.